# UIViewController In UICollectionview Cell disappears when partially reloading data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to dequeue a `viewController` view in a `collectionView` cell and it works like a charm, but when I try to reload data for a `Section` or an `indexPath` the view controller disappears. It doesn't happen when I do a full `collectionView.reloadData()` but I need to only reload an `indexPath`. Does someone know how to keep the view after reloading the `collectionView` particularly without fully reinitializing the `viewController`?

here's how I load my `viewController`, `ContainerCollectionViewCell` is just a cell with a container view that takes the child view passed in the function.

```
 private func onAction() {
     collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)])
 }

  private lazy var myViewcontroller: CustomViewController = {
            let viewController = CustomViewController()
            viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            addChild(viewController)
            viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
            
            return viewController
        }()

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let childView: UIView
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            childView = UIView()
            childView.backgroundColor = .red
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            childView = myViewController.view
        } else {
            childView = UIView()
            childView.backgroundColor = .blue
        }
                 return ContainerCollectionViewCell.dequeueCell(collectionView: collectionView, for: indexPath, childView: childView)
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 3
 }

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
     return 1
}
```

And here's the `ContainerCollectionViewCell`

```
class ContainerCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var childView: UIView? {
    didSet { configureView() }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

static func dequeueCell(collectionView: UICollectionView, for indexPath: IndexPath, childView: UIView?) -> ContainerCollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as? ContainerCollectionViewCell else { fatalError() }
    cell.childView = childView
    return cell
}

// MARK: - UICollectionReusableView methods
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    guard let childView = childView else { return }
    childView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.childView = nil
}

private func configureView() {
    guard let childView = childView else { return }
    childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(childView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        childView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        childView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `ContainerCollectionViewCell func dequeueCell(collectionView:for:childView:) -> UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: I edited the code sample in my question